# How to get a previously passed variable in reactor?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

I am making a discord bot as a personal project that is built on top of project-reactor?

I need to call a function that needs to get a variable that is passed further up the chain.

From the code below, I need to pass in two arguments. The first one needs the argument from MessageCreateEvent event and the second one from getContent.

How can I do this, I am new to using reactor.

```
    discordClient.getEventDispatcher().on(MessageCreateEvent.class)
            .map(MessageCreateEvent::getMessage)
            .map(Message::getContent)
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(o -> o.get())
            .map(this::getCommand)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(msg -> msg.runCommand(null, null))
            .subscribe();
```

I also tried this, but I am not seeing the runCommand() being called.:

```
    discordClient.getEventDispatcher().on(MessageCreateEvent.class)
            .flatMap(event ->
                Mono.just(event)
                .map(MessageCreateEvent::getMessage)
                .map(Message::getContent)
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(o -> o.get())
                .map(this::getCommand)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(msg -> msg.runCommand(event, null))
            )
            .subscribe();
```

Comment: You cannot. You'll need to either use nested fluxes with `flatMap` or pass tuples. Personally I prefer the former solution.

Comment: How do you make them? I thought it just be adding a flatMap after event and then add in a (event -> rest of code past on()), but the runCommand is not being called.

Comment: You have no `doOnError`, no `doOnNext`. You just call `subscribe()` and drop the result on the floor - how do you know what is and isn't called?

Comment: two possibilities come to mind: you're executing this in a test/main and the thread exits before the sequence has had a chance to run (asynchronous) OR the message gets filtered out (no content/null command). as suggested below, you can use `log()` to get a better understanding of what happens at which step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flatMap is fine. The error is probably somewhere other than you expect. This might help you to work out what is going on (assuming you have a logger object available called "log"):

```
Mono.just(event)
    .doOnNext(log::info)
    .map(MessageCreateEvent::getMessage)
    .doOnNext(log::info)
```

and so on for every line of your stream. On the last line you might like to add:

```
.doOnEach(s -> log.info("signal: " + s)))
```

FYI, or for others that stumble upon this, technically there *is* a way to use something passed in up the chain, zipWhen():

```
discordClient
    .getEventDispatcher()
    .on(MessageCreateEvent.class)
    .zipWhen(
        event ->
            Mono.just(event)
                .map(MessageCreateEvent::getMessage)
                .map(Message::getContent)
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(o -> o.get())
                .map(this::getCommand)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull),
        (event, msg) -> msg.runCommand(event, null))
    .subscribe();
```

but this doesn't make your code any cleaner! For certain other cases though, it can be handy.

Comment: there is also the `.log()` built-in operator for logging all events that reach a particular step. will pick up on slf4j, jdk logging or even default to console.

Comment: @SimonBaslé true. The nice thing about doing it manually with doOnNext is that you see the values progress and get transformed through your stream. You could also use .log() at every step, but then you see all the signals repeatedly.